# Description of an active person

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary, idiom-request

If *something* is up and running, it is in operation:

> 1. The engineer soon got the *air-conditioning* **up and running** again.
> 2. The Transfer *Council* is **up and running**.
> 3. The Conference has tried for over 10 years to get this *organization* **up and running**.

What words/phrases/idioms could we use to describe a *person* who is fully prepared (for the day, work etc.) and is already working?

The other day I heard "I am up and running" but it sound like a metaphor to me because a system or a machine is usually up and running. So, what would you say to describe such an active person, presumably an early riser, who is already up and... well, running errands, working hard etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [ready and raring to go](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raring)

> full of enthusiasm or eagerness (M-W)

### [‘I'll be ready and raring to go’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raring)

> Very enthusiastic and eager to do something (OD)

### [After a good night's sleep, Paul said he was raring to go.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-raring-to-go)

> If you say that you are *raring to go*, you mean that you are very eager to start doing something. (CD)

Answer (score 1):

There could be many, but I generally use...

> alive and kicking

If you are *alive and kicking,* you are full of vigor, enthusiasm, and liveliness.

Note that there are many occasions where you use this phrase major being in the context of someone who's recovered from some illness.

Interestingly, you can also use this phrase not just for humans but also for [industries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alive%20and%20kicking).

> After years of slow earnings, the industry is now alive and kicking!

Comment: I don't think **alive and kicking** is apt for someone who is prepared to focus on the work of the day. It does mean "energetic" but it's not really focused energy. As you say with your recuperation from illness example, the phrase has also come to have a jaunty ironic meaning: *I'm slower now but I'm not dead yet!*

Answer (score 1):

We also say **ready to hit the ground running**.

> She woke up ready to hit the ground running. She had a lot to do.